# Why are "is" and "remembered" used together in "M S Dhoni is remembered by the era he forged..."?

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice

> M S Dhoni **is remembered** by the era he forged after those dark days in
>   West Indies in 2007 when India crashed out in the group stage of the
>   World Cup after having gone down to Banglades

In this sentence, why **is** and **remembered** used in combined?

Comment: "M S Dhoni is (still) remembered..."

Comment: Are you familiar with the passive voice?

Comment: Side note: normally we would say "is remembered **for** {some accomplishment}" and "is remembered **by** {those who recall his accomplishment}"

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is in the passive voice, **"people remember him by his era".**

**"Is remembered"** means that someone/somebody remembers him *(maybe even everyone/everybody).*